# Getting error when running a sql select statement in python

Tags: python, sql

I am new to this and trying to learn python. I wrote a select statement in python where I used a parameter

```
Select """cln.customer_uid = """[(num_cuid_number)])
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Can you edit your post with the rest of the code? That error could be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: add your code ...we need more information for to help you

Comment: This is not Python code.  Please show us the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the others, this doesn't look really like Python by itself.

I will see even without seeing the rest of that code I'll guess the [(num_cuid_number)] value(s) being returned is a string, so you'll want to convert it to integer for the select statement to process.

Answer (score 0):

`num_cuid_number` is most likely a string in your code; the string indices are the ones in the square brackets. So please first check your data variable to see what you received there. Also, I think that `num_cuid_number` is a string, while it should be in an integer value.

**Let me give you an example for the python code to execute: (Just for the reference: I have used SQLAlchemy with flask)**

```
@app.route('/get_data/')
def get_data():

base_sql="""
    SELECT cln.customer_uid='%s' from cln
""" % (num_cuid_number)

data = db.session.execute(base_sql).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are trying to create a select statement with a "where" clause here. There are many ways to do this, for example using raw sql, the query should look similar to this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM cln WHERE customer_uid = %s"
parameters = (num_cuid_number,)
```

separating the parameters from the query is secure. You can then take these 2 variables and execute them with your db engine like

```
results = db.execute(query, parameters)
```

This will work, however, especially in Python, it is more common to use a package like SQLAlchemy to make queries more "flexible" (in other words, without manually constructing an actual string as a query string). You can do the same thing using SQLAlchemy core functionality

```
query = cln.select()
query = query.where(cln.customer_uid == num_cuid_number)
results = db.execute(query)
```

Note: I simplified "db" in both examples, you'd actually use a cursor, session, engine or similar to execute your queries, but that wasn't your question.